# Retrieve more than 255 characters from a query field

Tags: vba, character

I have a query that displays more than 255 characters in a field, and I want to put that data into a variable that I can process. Unfortunately, MS Access truncates the field value return to 255 characters.

(At least when using this method:)

```
MyVar = Nz(rst.Fields("myfield").Value)
```

Most of the workarounds I've found online suggest to create a table, modify the desired field setting to Long Text, and then migrate the data from the query to the table, but I'm getting the same results. The Long Text field is still truncated during the DoCmd execution.

(At least when I do it this way:)

```
CurrentDB.Execute "Insert Into target_table Select myquery.* From myquery"
```

Other suggestions mention to change the field to group by "First", but the field reverts to "Expression" when run because the field definition includes a function that runs during the query to manipulate the results.

The query also isn't mine and is rather complicated, using other field expressions that call other functions across tables. I would like to avoid reverse engineering the entire thing just to update a table if at all possible. The data is already on my screen, looking at me - I just want to be able to use it.

It's a very Microsoft-ish solution for an MS product to display some data and then tell you it can't find the stuff it just gave you (I'm looking at you, file explorer), but I'm hoping someone here might have a viable suggestion. Perhaps some other query-to-table methods that don't truncate? Some other query setting, or field retrieval method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim MyVar As String
Dim Value As Variant

Value = rst.Fields("myfield").Value
MyVar = Nz(Value)
```

In any case, this works:

```
MyVar = Nz(DLookup("myfield", "myquery", "Id = " & someId & ""))
```

However, most likely your *myquery* is the limiting factor. It must be a straight select query to not truncate memo-fields.

Comment: Ah, DLookup! You're a godsend, thanks! Much appreciated.